# Как закрыть все открытые теги и добавить открывающие всем закрывающим, у которых нет пары?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть строка, содержащая произвольный набор скобок (тегов):  `()((())[[[[]}}{`.

Нужно проверить, есть ли у каждой открывающей скобки закрывающая ее пара, если нет то поставить.

И наоборот если в строке есть закрывающая скобка без открывающей ее пары, то нужно перед ней добавить открытие.

То есть, если наша строка выглядела вот так:`()((())[[[[]}}{` то надо сделать `()((()))[[[[]]]]{{}}{}`;

Методом гугления нашел только, как проверить такую строку на то, чтобы все скобки имели закрывающую пару.

написал следующую функцию, но желаемого результата не получил

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var string_array = ('()((()))[[[[]{{}}{').split('');
    console.log(close_tags(string_array, 0, string_array.length));
  });

  let openedtags = {
    "[": "]",
    "{": "}",
    "(": ")",
  }; //тег открыт

  let closedtags = { //открывающие пары для закрывающих тегов
    "]": "[",
    "}": "{",
    ")": "(",
  }

  let opentags = [];

  function close_tags(string_array, i, len) {
    if (len > i) {
      if (openedtags[string_array[i]]) { //если тег открыт
        opentags.push(string_array[i]); //запоминаем его
        i = i + 1;
        close_tags(string_array, i, len); //и переходим к следующему тегу
      } else { //если тег закрыт
        //смотрим совпадает ли открывающий парный эемент с поледним в массиве 
        if (opentags[opentags.length - 1] == closedtags[string_array[i]]) { //если совпал
          opentags.pop(); //удаляем из массива
          i = i + 1;
          close_tags(string_array, i, len); //и переходим к следующему тегу
        } else { //если нет
          string_array.splice(i - 1, 0, closedtags[string_array[i]]); //добавляем перед ним открывающую пару
          i = i + 2;
          close_tags(string_array, i, len); //и переходим к следующему тегу
        }
      }
    } else {
      opentags.reverse().forEach(function(tag) {
        string_array.push(closedtags[tag]);
      })
    }
    return string_array.join("");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Поехали">
```

Comment: Очень интересно, откуда растут ноги у такой задачи) Это упрощенная версия чего-то более запутанного, или просто учебная задачка? Не представляю, где может пригодится...

Comment: Что должно получиться для строки `([`? ``()[]` или `([])`?

Comment: @Yaant, по логике моего сприпта `([])`. То есть мы перебираем все открывающие теги. и помещаем их в массив. Если в строке только открывающие теги, то просто переходим в конец моей функции. И в обратном порядке подставляем закрывающие теги

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const source = '[{[({]';

const OPENED_BRACKETS = {
  "[": "]",
  "{": "}",
  "(": ")",
};

const CLOSED_BRACKETS = {
  "]": "[",
  "}": "{",
  ")": "(",
};

function closeBrackets(sourceString, openedBrackets, i) {
  if (i < sourceString.length) {
    if (OPENED_BRACKETS[sourceString[i]]) {
      openedBrackets.push(sourceString[i]);
      closeBrackets(sourceString, openedBrackets, i + 1)
    } else {
      if (openedBrackets[openedBrackets.length - 1] === CLOSED_BRACKETS[sourceString[i]]) {
        openedBrackets.pop();
        closeBrackets(sourceString, openedBrackets, i + 1)
      } else {
        sourceString.splice(i, 0, CLOSED_BRACKETS[sourceString[i]]);
        closeBrackets(sourceString, openedBrackets, i + 2)
      }
    }
  } else {
    openedBrackets.reverse().forEach(function(item) {
      sourceString.push(OPENED_BRACKETS[item])
    });
  }

  return sourceString.join('')
}


console.log(closeBrackets(source.split(''), [], 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил сначала разобраться с половиной задачи: Научиться хотя бы закрывать все открытые скобки слева направо, а лишние закрывающие не трогать. После чего можно отзеркалить строку и повторить процедуру.

```js
let test = [
  "()((())[[[[]}}{{{",
  "(((())]}]}[]}{[]}",
  "([]([]][][][][[}}",
  "(a)a(a(a(a)a)a[a[a[a[a]a}a}a{a",
].map(e => e + " >>> " + autoCorrect(e));

console.log(test);

/***/

function autoCorrect(str) {
  let _o = new Lib();

  str = _o.mirror(correctToLeft(str));

  return _o.mirror(correctToLeft(str)).join("");

  /***/

  function correctToLeft(str) {
    let result = [];
    for (let char of str) {
      if ( _o.isClosing(char) ) {
        if ( _o.openingPair(char) === _o.stackLast() ) {
          _o.openingStack.pop();
        } else {
          result = result.concat( _o.getStackCloser({clear: true}) );
        }
      } else if ( _o.isOpening(char) ) {
        _o.openingStack.push(char);
      }

      result.push(char);
    }

    return result.concat( _o.getStackCloser({clear: true}) );
  }

  /*****/

  function Lib() {
    this.pair = {
      "{": "}",
      "}": "{",
      "(": ")",
      ")": "(",
      "[": "]",
      "]": "[",
    };
    this.openingStack = [];

    this.getStackCloser = function({
      clear
    }) {
      let str = this.openingStack.map(scope => this.pair[scope]).slice().reverse();
      if (clear) this.openingStack = [];

      return str;
    }
    this.stackLast = () => this.openingStack[this.openingStack.length - 1];

    this.isClosing = (char) => /\]|\}|\)/.test(char);
    this.isOpening = (char) => /\[|\{|\(/.test(char);
    this.openingPair = (char) => this.pair[char];

    this.mirror = function(arr) {
      return arr.slice().reverse().map(char => this.pair[char] || char);
    }
  }
}
```